# drop table in python with sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have question about python and sqlite3.  I want to drop a table from within Python.  The command

```
cur.execute('drop table if exists tab1')
```

Does not work.

```
cur.executescript('drop table if exists tab1;')
```

does the job.

The execute method allows the creation of tables.  However, it won't drop them?  Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `cur.executescript` command issues a `COMMIT` before running the provided script.  Additionally a `CREATE` executes a `COMMIT` intrinsically.  Perhaps you have an open transaction that needs committed before your changes take place.

Comment: What if drop table by sqlite3.connect('disk_sqlite3').cursor().execute() works while sqlite3.connect(':memory:').cursor().execute() does not?